# Troubles with parsing nested knockout viewmodels to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-2.0

#### The problem

As I was working and exploring knockoutjs, I got stuck at some point. I want to serialize a viewmodel (and underlying viewmodels) to JSON. This will end up in an infinite loop because the child viewmodels have a property which references the parent viewmodel. What is the best practice for solving this issue?

#### The code

```
var Partner = function (parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.parent = parent;
    self.name = ko.observable('');
}

var ProjectViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.nr = ko.observable(0);
    self.tite = ko.observable('');
    self.partners = ko.observableArray();            

    self.addPartner = function () { self.partners.push(new Partner(self)) };
    self.removePartner = function (c) { self.partners.remove(c) };
};
var vm = new ProjectViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);


$("#button").click(function () {
    alert(ko.toJSON(vm));
}
```

#### What I tried so far

I tried adding the following method in the Partner viewmodel:

```
Partner.prototype.toJSON = function () {
            var copy = ko.toJS(self);
            delete copy.parent;
            return copy;
        }
```

This works with only one Partner, if the ProjectViewModel has multipe partners, every partner will have the same value as the last partner. This happens only when I want to serialize it to JSON.

Comment: Well, the cause of this problem was completely my own fault. Besides that, if I had to write my current application without KO, I would probably not be able to make it a single page application. The code would be at least 5 times longer and more complex.

Comment: you got my curiosity... see i made this small data visualization app dealing with only 5mb of raw data and only about 200 different view combinations (2 view mode, 3 criteria to select, with different options depending on option selected in the others); i built my index algo & event manually using jquery & the resulting script is 23kb minified working in ie6+ & the rest; so for you 5 times bigger than ko is like 200kb minified that's like my app * 10 = 20 view mode or 60 select depending on each other with 2000 different viewing combination in a single page... wahoo that's huge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to handle this situation.  The `ko.toJS` part of KO handles this properly. It is ultimately `JSON.stringify` (called after `ko.toJS` in `ko.toJSON` that causes the error.

Your `toJSON` method on your prototype is pretty close, except that you want to be dealing with `this` rather than `self`.

So, it would look like:

```
Partner.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  var copy = ko.toJS(this);
  delete copy.parent;
  return copy; 
};
```

Other ways to handle it:

1- don't actually store your parent on the child object and just reference it in any handlers directly based on the argument passed to the constructor.

```
var Partner = function (parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);

    self.doSomething = function() {
        //can use "parent" directly here without storing it anywhere
    };
};
```

2- "hide" your parent reference

```
var Partner = function (parent) {
    var self = this;
    self.meta = function() {};
    self.meta.parent = parent;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);    
};
```

You can place your `parent` value behind a function (could be as a sub-property of an observable).  When your structure is turned into a plain JS object by `ko.toJS`, then any sub-properties of functions are lost.

3- change the structure of your application, depending on what you want to do.  Suppose that the parent wants to react whenever a child has it's name changed.  You could pass in a callback, setup the subscription, and execute it whenever it changes

```
var Partner = function (nameChangedCallback) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(name);    

    if (typeof nameChangedCallback == "function") {
        self.name.subscribe(function() {
           nameChangedCallback.call(self, self);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: As this is just a simplified version of the code, and on the original version I have even more nested viewmodels, correcting the toJSON solved the problem. Thanks!